# Unable to boot: No boot options

Tags: 14.04

I have dual booted Windows10 and Ubuntu 14.04, which has been working properly for about two weeks. I then had issues with grub (it would boot straight into Windows), which I fixed using boot-repair on my Ubuntu installation usb. After fixing that and checking to make sure both Windows and Ubuntu work, I continued working from my Ubuntu side for 6 hours. Everything worked. I shut off my computer properly for the night and when I booted it up again this morning it went straight to BIOS with no boot options. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Apparently Asus has an issue with a screw that comes loose. This screw, which connected the hard drive bracket to the computer, happened to come off and rest on the exposed pins of the hdd essentially jumpering them. I just put the screw back in its rightful place and everything came back!